# Cannot link facebook photos to my website?

Tags: facebook, image-gallery, blueimp

I am following a guide from this link https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

But I am getting this error? should i connect this to a database? Why is that the data is not working?

[image]

This is the code on index and I am very sure that my app id and secret id is correct:

```
<?php
 $page_title = "Photo Albums";
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.col-md-4{
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <?php

 echo "<div class='col-lg-12'>";
 echo "<h1 class='page-header'>{$page_title}</h1>";
 echo "</div>";

 $access_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

 $fields="id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count";
 $fb_page_id = "1129048493791399";

 $json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}";
 $json = file_get_contents($json_link);

 $obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

 $album_count = count($obj['data']);
 for($x=0; $x<$album_count; $x++){

 $id = isset($obj['data'][$x]['id']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['id'] : "";
 $name = isset($obj['data'][$x]['name']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['name'] : "";
 $url_name=urlencode($name);
 $description = isset($obj['data'][$x]['description']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['description'] : "";
 $link = isset($obj['data'][$x]['link']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['link'] : "";

 $cover_photo = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo'] : "";
// use this for newer access tokens:
 // $cover_photo = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo']['id']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo']['id'] : "";
$count = isset($obj['data'][$x]['count']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['count'] : "";

// if you want to exclude an album, just add the name on the if statement
if(
    $name!="Profile Pictures" &&
    $name!="Cover Photos" &&
    $name!="Timeline Photos"
){

    $show_pictures_link = "photos.php?album_id={$id}&album_name={$name}";

    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
        echo "<a href='{$show_pictures_link}'>";
            echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$cover_photo}/picture?access_token={$access_token}' alt=''>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo "<h3>";
            echo "<a href='{$show_pictures_link}'>{$name}</a>";
        echo "</h3>";

        $count_text="Photo";
        if($count>1){ $count_text="Photos"; }

        echo "<p>";
            echo "<div style='color:#888;'>{$count} {$count_text} / <a href='{$link}' target='_blank'>View on Facebook</a></div>";
            echo $description;
        echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
}
?>

 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">       </script>
 <![endif]-->

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https instead, trying to use this link by typing it into the browser gives a more helpful error:

> {
>
> "error": {
>
> "message": "You must use https:// when passing an access token",
>
> "type": "OAuthException",
>
> "code": 1
>
> }
>
> }

Using https manually gave 3 results, including medicines.